# How do you convert text into a wire frame look?

Tags: animation, text-object

How do you convert text into a wire frame look?

I want to convert some text into a wire frame look in blender 2.8

Alt + c doesn't work in 2.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert options are available through the Menu bar:

*Object > Convert to > Mesh from text*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the text "Wireframe" in the viewport, you can go to the object settings, and set the *Maximum Draw Type* to wire. If you want to make actual renderable text that looks like it's made out of wire, you can do this by enabling the "Add advanced objects" add-on in the Blender Preferences. This will give you an option to add a wireframe-like mesh of an object based off of the object's edges. You can access it in the *Add objects* panel. I made one here:
[image]
The one on the right is the mesh, the one on the left is the wireframe text.
I had to go into edit mode, and make the top and bottom faces one mesh, so the final text didn't look weird. You may have to do this.
 One other thing you can do is to add a *wireframe* modifier, which is basically the "easy" way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Right click the text and a menu will pop up, then click Convert to and then click on Mesh from Curve/Meta/Surf/Text

Comment: This is exactly the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

An updated answer using Blender 3.5

**1.** Right-click the text and convert to curve.

[image]

**2.** On the Object Data tab, under shape, change the fill mode to none.

[image]

**3.** And under Bevel add a bit of Depth. I added too much on the example because I want it to be noticeable.

[image]